# Best distro for 10+ years old ThinkPad

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu, mint, distro-recommendation

I’m looking for a distro which can help me with search web, watch videos without lag and maybe use libra with my 10+ years old ThinkPad. I don’t remember the specs of laptop but it’s an old ThinkPad. Saw some vids about linux mint but I can’t decide between mint and other light distros. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS with SSD and maximal amount of RAM suitable for this laptop model. Check the options on http://thinkwiki.org/wiki/ .

Answer (score 3):

I am using LUbuntu on several ages-old computers with Intel Core2Duo and 2GB RAM and it works like a charm. Exactly for a video playing, e-mail, some LibreOffice editing, etc. Firefox starts somewhat slow, but once started goes ok.

Comment: But is it true that Lubuntu crashes so much? They say Mint is way reliable than Lubuntu. And if Mint is better do you suggest Cinnamon, MATE or XFCE and why. Thanks again.

Comment: I can't see why Mint can crash less than Lubuntu (or any Ubuntu), as Linux Mint uses *runtime adjustments* causing it to slow & adding an extra layer of complexity and more chance of crashing (let alone attack vector lowering security), so that Linux Mint can use the foreign (Ubuntu) packages they have no control over.  Adding extra code meaning more resources are required to achieve the same result does not generally improve stability - it lowers it, so I'd suggest questioning your "they say" people as they don't sound very knowledgeable of how systems work. Lubuntu is adjustment free @coupre

Comment: I had no problem with LUbuntu crashes. Superstable for me.